# How to build an android app using another android app?

Tags: java, android, apk

The parent application (App A) is being used to setup how the child application(App B) will looks like. To be specific, user who run App A choose which Folder/File/Sound/Image can be accessed by App B.

After App A finish chosen, it will generate App B that only the chosen Folder/File/Sound/Image can be view/access.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to use Broadcast Receiver, where App B receives a specific Intent with some informations (passed through Extras in Intent).

App A can't access shared preferences (or internal database) of App B.

For example (in App B implements this):

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      // Setup look and feel of App B
   }
}
```

In MainActivity of App B:

```
public onCreate(...) {
     registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), new IntentFilter("com.myapp.foo.CUSTOM_INTENT"));
}
```

In App A (call you broadcast receiver in App B):

```
public void broadcastIntent(View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("com.myapp.foo.CUSTOM_INTENT");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps you!